# How do I convert an HTML5 Canvas arc() to JavaFX 2.x Canvas arc()?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, javafx

I wish to convert a statement from JavaScript used in an HTML5 Canvas such as:

```
ctx.arc(x, y, (rad+5)*factor, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
```

to the equivalent statement in JavaFX.

What would it look like?

For reference, in HTML5 Canvas the arc() method is defined as:

```
x   The x-coordinate of the center of the circle
y   The y-coordinate of the center of the circle
r   The radius of the circle
sAngle  The starting angle, in radians (0 is at the 3 o'clock position of the arc's circle)
eAngle  The ending angle, in radians
counterclockwise    Optional. Specifies whether the drawing should be counterclockwise or clockwise. False=clockwise, true=counter-clockwise
```

but in JavaFX it is defined as:

```
public void arc(double centerX, double centerY, double radiusX, double radiusY, double startAngle, double length)

Adds path elements to the current path to make an arc that uses Euclidean degrees. This Euclidean orientation sweeps from East to North, then West, then South, then back to East.

Parameters:
    centerX - the center x position of the arc.
    centerY - the center y position of the arc.
    radiusX - the x radius of the arc.
    radiusY - the y radius of the arc.
    startAngle - the starting angle of the arc in the range 0-360.0
    length - the length of the baseline of the arc.
```

Could someone please show me what the JavaFX arc() statement would look like and explain how to convert between these two? Or should I be using arcTo() or something else entirely?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent statement of this:

```
var rad=10;
var factor=5; 
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, (rad+5)*factor, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
```

in javafx would be:

```
int rad=10;
int factor=5;
graphicsContext.strokeArc(x, y, (rad+5)*factor,(rad+5)*factor, 0, 360, ArcType.OPEN);
```

The angles in HTML5 are in radians, and in Java in degrees. also Java has 2 radius parameters to make it more general as you can draw ellipse arcs.